# Spring HATEOAS, how to handle conversion links to entities without flooding the DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring boot 2.3, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS, Hibernate.
Let's think to a simple use case like an user creating an invoice in a web client, or a inventory list for a warehouse. When the user submit the form, could be sent hundreds or rows and these rows can have links to other entities.

In the case of the invoice, for example, each row can have a product reference that will be passed to the sever as a link.

That link is translated by Spring into an entity using `Repository`. My point is that for every row, a query to get the product runs.
This means that everything will be really slow during insert (n+1 select problem).

Probably I missed somthing in the logic, but I didn't see concrete examples that focus on how to handle a big quantity of translations link -> entity.

Do you have any hint about it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your point about many entities that will be created if linked entities will be returned to server? Hibernate (as well as spring) has lazy loading mechanism - https://blog.ippon.tech/boost-the-performance-of-your-spring-data-jpa-application/, so only necessary entities will be populated. Please, correct me if I miss understand your questions.

Comment: Actually that's not what I meant. I have to save 100 rows for an invoice. 100 rows with 100 different products, prices, etc. I can't use lazy loading because to save rows in the db I need the product object. As soon the link like https://myapp.com/api/v1/products/1 arrive to the server, a SELECT is done to retrieve the product. This is done 100 times if I've 100 different products. This is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Got your point; it won’t happen, because if you’ll be using hibernate and will configure entities properly then hibernate will construct join between tables and fetch 100 records from join table (with fields populated there). In other way, if you are going to use JPA repository, you may construct custom query by your own, so you define which values to return from database (through @Query parameter)

Comment: I've to create something custom, am I right? This doesn't come out of the box with Spring HATEOAS, Spring Data REST and Hibernate....

Comment: If you would define your data model with spring data correctly, you’ll get it out of the box; here is the simple example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships